# A question at mathematics.SE

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

There is a question [Interacting with high school teachers (US)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/764894/26306), that fits our scope, but not that of mathematics.SE where it was asked. It would be great if it could be moved here, but I'm not sure if is possible (MESE is beta). Also, the OP is uncertain about the outcome:

> I can reasonably expect math educators to start pointing fingers at me saying that I don't respect the work of a high school teacher, so the question will endi up with -15 score

What is your opinion?

Right now there aren't many favorable votes and in my opinion rightly so, because it's not about mathematics. However, if you think that it belongs here, we could for example show some support, like comment that it would be welcomed here and vote that comment up.

Comment: The question mentioned has been migrated to [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/1922/77).

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is a good fit for MESE. I upvoted for the comment and I'm glad it has been transferred here. Let's do our best.